# How i can get also null values with normal values with same sequence

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I want to get data from the database including null values that show in concat as the query working
The database structure of data and result of query attached images, I want all answers values including null

Here is my query;

```
$list = Modelname::where('cid', 293)
    ->whereIn('qid',[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
    ->select('created_at')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(answer) as answer')
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Query result:

```
{"created_at":"2021-03-15T01:12:12.000000Z","username":"managers","item":"6,6,6,6,6","ids":"1881,1882,1883,1884,1885","qids":"19,20,21,22,23"},
```

[My database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMhOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `orWhere()` method.

Example:

```
$list = Modelname::where('cid', 293)
    ->whereIn('qid',[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
    ->orWhere('qid', null) // orWhere here
    ->select('created_at')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(answer) as answer')
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Or just add `null` to your array like that:

```
$list = Modelname::where('cid', 293)
    ->whereIn('qid',[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, null]) // null here
    ->select('created_at')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(answer) as answer')
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get()
```

Comment: Its not return the null value of the answer column I need null values of answer values

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql  [IfNull](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp) to get the null result as a string:

```
$list = Modelname::where('cid', 293)
    ->whereIn('qid',[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
    ->select('created_at')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(answer, '=', 
                 IFNULL(answer, 'NULL'))) as answer')
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```